# Pyspark Inferring Timezone by location

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timezone

I'm trying to infer timezone in PySpark given the longitude and latitude of an event. I came across the [`timezonefinder`](https://pypi.org/project/timezonefinder/) library which works locally. I wrapped it in a user defined function in an attempt to use it as the timezone inferrer.

```py
def get_timezone(longitude, latitude):
    from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder
    tzf = TimezoneFinder()
    return tzf.timezone_at(lng=longitude, lat=latitude)

udf_timezone = F.udf(get_timezone, StringType())

df = sqlContext.read.parquet(INPUT)
df.withColumn("local_timezone", udf_timezone(df.longitude, df.latitude))\
  .write.parquet(OUTPUT)
```

When I run on a single node, this code works. However, when running in parallel, I get the following error:

```
  File "/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1525907011747_0007/container_1525907011747_0007_01_000062/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1525907011747_0007/container_1525907011747_0007_01_000062/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1525907011747_0007/container_1525907011747_0007_01_000062/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 104, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1525907011747_0007/container_1525907011747_0007_01_000062/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/tmp/c95422912bfb4079b64b88427991552a/enrich_data.py", line 64, in  get_timezone
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/timezonefinder/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/timezonefinder/timezonefinder.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .helpers_numba import coord2int, int2coord, distance_to_polygon_exact, distance_to_polygon, inside_polygon, \
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/timezonefinder/helpers_numba.py", line 17, in <module>
    @jit(b1(i4, i4, i4[:, :]), nopython=True, cache=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/decorators.py", line 191, in wrapper
    disp.enable_caching()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 529, in enable_caching
    self._cache = FunctionCache(self.py_func)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/caching.py", line 614, in __init__
    self._impl = self._impl_class(py_func)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/caching.py", line 349, in __init__
    "for file %r" % (qualname, source_path))
RuntimeError: cannot cache function 'inside_polygon': no locator available for file '/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/timezonefinder/helpers_numba.py'
```

I can import the library locally on the nodes where I got the error. 
Any solution along these line would be appreciated:

- Is there a native Spark to do the task?
- Is there another way to load the library?
- Is there a way to avoid caching `numba` does?

Comment: Sounds like you should raise an issue [in the project's bug tracker](https://github.com/MrMinimal64/timezonefinder/issues).  StackOverflow isn't the best place for bug reporting.  That said, perhaps someone has a workaround for this class of PySpark problems, but I doubt you will get timezonefinder specific help without going through GitHub to the library's authors.  Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this was solved by abandoning `timezonefinder` completely, and instead, using the geo-spatial timezone dataset from [`timezone-boundary-builder`](https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder), while querying using [`magellan`](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan), the geo-spatial sql query library for spark.

One caveat I had was the fact that the `Point` and other objects in the library were not wrapped for Python. I ended up writing my own scala function for timezone matching, and dropped the objects from `magellan` before returning the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this error when running timezonefinder on spark cluster.

```
RuntimeError: cannot cache function 'inside_polygon': no locator available for file '/disk-1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/timezonefinder1.zip/timezonefinder/helpers_numba.py'
```

The issue was that numpy versions were different on cluster and timezonefinder package that we shipped to spark. 
Cluster had numpy - 1.13.3 where as numpy on timezonefinder.zip was 1.17.2.

To overcome version mismatches, we created a custom conda environment with timezonefinder and numpy 1.17.2 and submitted spark job using custom conda environment.

**Creating Custom Conda Environment with timezonefinder package installed:**

1. conda create --name timezone-conda python timezonefinder
2. source activate timezone-conda
3. conda install -y conda-pack
4. conda pack -o timezonecondaevnv.tar.gz -d ./MY_CONDA_ENV

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

**Submitting spark job with custom conda environment:**

```
!spark-submit --name app_name \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 1024m \
--executor-memory 1GB \
--executor-cores 5 \
--num-executors 10 \
--queue QUEUE_NAME\
--archives ./timezonecondaevnv.tar.gz#MY_CONDA_ENV \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./MY_CONDA_ENV/bin/python \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./MY_CONDA_ENV/bin/python \
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./MY_CONDA_ENV/bin/python \
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./MY_CONDA_ENV/bin/python \
./main.py
```